# Как отключить определенный button в react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как мне отключить определенную кнопку а не все, данные приходят с сервера, кнопок может быть много но отключить нужно определенную.

```
  <div
                               className="card"
                               style={{ width: 18 + "rem" }}
                               key={`${index}`}
                           >
                               <img src={post.url} className="card-img-top" alt="..." />
                               <div className="card-body">
                                   <h5 className="card-title">{post.title}</h5>
                                   <p className="card-text">{post.content}</p>
                                   <a href="/" className="btn btn-primary">
                                       {post.category}
                                   </a>
                                   <button onClick={() => like(index)} disabled>Like</button>
                                   <h3>{post.likes} likes</h3>
                               </div>
                           </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<div
                               className="card"
                               style={{ width: 18 + "rem" }}
                               key={`${index}`}
                           >
                               <img src={post.url} className="card-img-top" alt="..." />
                               <div className="card-body">
                                   <h5 className="card-title">{post.title}</h5>
                                   <p className="card-text">{post.content}</p>
                                   <a href="/" className="btn btn-primary">
                                       {post.category}
                                   </a>
                                   <button onClick={() => like(index)} disabled={index === 1(или id который нужен) && true}>Like</button>
                                   <h3>{post.likes} likes</h3>
                               </div>
                           </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большо, помогло, подскажите пожалуйста а как можно теперь по клику на кнопку отключить также определенную кнопку и сделать так чтоб она отключена была всегда если была нажата кнопка?

Comment: Есть много разных способов. Вам надо попытаться сделать самим - если не получится задать вопрос, с описанием того как пытались.